# What value is in the variable myletter after the above code executes?

Tags: java

According to the ASCII table for the char variable 'e' it seems that corresponds to 65. The code goes like this

```
char myletter = 'e';
myletter++;
```

I know that you add 1 to the variable myletter by the post increment. I assuming is 66 but it is not. Can someone tell me the real value? I know,Im in the right track. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just run the code and print it to the console?

Comment: @Stultuske  I ran the code and the correct answer is f. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> According to the ASCII table for the char variable `'e'` it seems that corresponds to 65.

Lowercase `'e'` is 65 HEX. In decimal that would be 101. When you increment it, you get 66 HEX, or 102 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to *dasblinkenlights*'s answer...The byte code will give you a clear idea of what is happening behind the scenes :

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_VARARGS
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: bipush        101 // push decimal value of 'e'
         2: istore_1
         3: iload_1
         4: iconst_1
         5: iadd            // add 1 to 101 ==> 102
         6: i2c             // convert 102 to char ==> f
         7: istore_1        // store it in the var myLetter
         8: return
```